# Quickest, Most Efficient Method of Retrieving XmlNode.InnerText

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I have an xml node structured as such:

```
<Event>
  <ID>173537</ID>
  <PrinterName>Kyocera FS-820 KX</PrinterName>
</Event>
```

In order to retrieve the InnerText of the ID and PrinterName nodes, I am using the following:

```
Dim id As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(nodeEvent.GetElementsByTagName("ID")(0).InnerText.Trim)
Dim printer As String = nodeEvent.GetElementsByTagName("PrinterName")(0).InnerText.Trim
```

It seems like there should be a more efficient, possibly quicker way of doing this rather than using the XmlNode.GetElementsByTagName method. In this case, there will never be more than one ID or PrinterName node. Should I be going about this in a different manner?

Comment: Well I'd use LINQ to XML, where in C# you'd just use: `decimal id = (decimal) nodeEvent.Element("ID");`. Are you sure `id` is really a natural `Decimal` rather than an integer?

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for the response. Yes, oddly enough the id does need to be and is a decimal. In my case I need to parse the xml as fast as possible, do you feel that using LINQ would be the faster method or is it just preference?

Comment: Perhaps I am lazy but I would have deserialized that to an object the minute it hits my system. This would ensure it is a valid graph and make any future references to it easier.

Comment: What are your performance criteria, and have you determined that the simplest code doesn't meet it? Note that "as fast as possible" is not a suitable criterion, unless you want to be micro-optimizing forever. (Maybe you want to build your own custom XML-parsing hardware? That could no doubt be faster than .NET, just to give a *reductio ad absurdum* example.)

Comment: To keep things simple lets say we kept "as fast as possible" within the confines of the already defined offerings of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

XMLReader is by far the quickest way to read XML.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmlreader

Performance:
https://www.altamiracorp.com/blog/employee-posts/performance-linq-to-sql-vs

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is a great option, you need to make a class that will receive the values in its properties, and then a simple, `XMLSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader)` and it will go to your object class, lets say:

```
class Event
{ 
     public int ID {get;set;} 
     public string PrinterName{ get;set;}
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

all the info you need to do this
good luck and happy coding